# Property 'zkUpgrades' does not exist on type 'HardhatRuntimeEnvironment'.ts(2339)

Tags: hardhat, typescript, zksync

I have a test file for testing an upgradable smart contract on zkSync by looking at the docs [here](https://era.zksync.io/docs/tools/hardhat/hardhat-zksync-upgradable.html#transparent-upgradable-proxies). I'm getting a typescript error on this line

```typescript
await hre.zkUpgrades.deployProxy(deployer.zkWallet, contract, [42]).then((r) => r.deployed());
```

error

> Property 'zkUpgrades' does not exist on type 'HardhatRuntimeEnvironment'.ts(2339)

The code runs fine but how do I get rid of the typescript complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the `hardhat.config.ts` file. The `HardhatUserConfig` was imported before the upgradable plugin, but it should be imported after the plugin is imported.

Before

```typescript
.
.
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/types";
.
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-upgradable";

.
.
.
```

After

```typescript
.
.
import "@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-upgradable";
.
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/types";

.
.
.
```